# How to give permissions to www-data to log in with ssh?

Tags: permissions, ssh, apache2

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server, where Apache runs as user www-data. I would like to be able to log into the server via ssh as www-data.

How can I define a password for www-data without breaking the Apache service?

How to add www-data to the list of allowed ssh users?

**Edit**

I understand from the question that was marked as duplicate, that it is not the most secure solution to give www-data access via ssh, but I need to do it for a different reason at least temporarily.

Here is the reason why I need to log into the server as www-data :
I want my webserver to ssh into a remote host without providing a password. In order to be able to set this up, I need to log in as www-data, generate a ssh key and send it to that remote host.

Comment: This question has been asked many times, the link I gave is IMO most secure. You would not want to give ssh (shell access) to var-www

Comment: @bodhi You are right, I found this question a couple of times, but the two sub-questions above were never clearly answered.

Comment: If you do not have root access, talk to your web host / sysadmin

Comment: No,  please re-read my question. It does not refer to the hosting account, but to my physical server.

Comment: you configure ssh in /var/www/sshd_config and set a password with passwd .

Comment: @bodhi OK, I understand so far, but isn't it breaking the Apache service, when I set a password on www-data? (maybe a stupid question, but on Windows I would have to set that password in the service startup parameters)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are three things to do to allow a 'service user' like www-data to login via ssh.

1. Set a password for www-data

   ```
   sudo passwd www-data
   ```
2. Define a shell for www-data. You can do this using `chsh` or by editing `/etc/passwd`. Replace `/usr/sbin/nologin` or similar by `/bin/bash` on the line of the user.
3. Give permission for login via ssh, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the following line (do not forget to enumerate all the users that need ssh access)

   ```
   AllowUsers www-data
   ```

Comment: It's essential to note "The permissions on /var/www/.ssh should be 700, and the permissions on the authorized_keys file should be 600."

Comment: /var/www should also be 700.

Comment: To debug permissions issues, run `grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log`